# Change route parameter by name without knowing full route

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In Angular 2, is it possible to get the current URL, modify a parameter by its configured name and then navigate to it?

Example routes

```
path: 'home'
path: 'heroes/:universe'
path: 'villains/:universe'
```

Valid URLs include:

- https://example.com/home
- https://example.com/heroes/marvel
- https://example.com/heroes/capcom
- https://example.com/villains/marvel
- https://example.com/villains/capcom

Now somewhere in the root component I'd like to have a selection of universes.

```
// in App.component.ts
universe: string;
```

---

```
<!-- in App.component.html -->
<select [(ngModel)]="universe" (ngModelChange)="navigateToUniverse($event)">
    <option value="marvel">Marvel</option>
    <option value="capcom">Capcom</option>
</select>
```

Examples

- The current route is `/heroes/marvel` and I select Capcom -> navigate to `/heroes/capcom`
- The current route is `/villains/marvel` and I select Capcom -> navigate to `/villains/capcom`

In my head, I imagine it should be possible to do this:

```
// in App.component.ts
navigateToUniverse(universe: string): void {
    /*
    * 1. get the route config of the current ActivatedRoute
    *    eg. /heroes/:universe
    *   -or- /villains/:universe
    *    (or /home)
    * 2. replace the :universe parameter with the selected value
    * 3. call Router.navigate with the new URL
    * /
}
```

I'm already stuck on the first step. There doesn't seem to be anything in `ActivatedRoute` that will get me the route config for the current route.

Comment: How are you going to figure out weather its a hero or a villian..??

Comment: By looking at the current route.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from `activatedRoute` property

```
constructor(protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

public loadData() {
    var route = this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path;
    console.log(route);
}
```

it will log your current route template. `"users/:id"` in my example. Please check.

Comment: That almost worked. I had to use the first child route of the activated route: `activatedRoute.firstChild.routeConfig.path`. I think it's because I wrote my code in the root component (`AppComponent`).

Comment: Glad to help you. We can update answer with your investigation result to help other users find solutions for similar problems faster.

Answer (score 1):

First import Router from @angular/router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private _router: Router){}

navigateToUniverse(universe: string): void {    

      // Use Router to get the current Url.

      let currentUrl = this._router.url;
      currentUrl = currentUrl.replace(currentUrl .substring(r.lastIndexOf('/')),'')

     // 2. replace the :universe parameter with the selected value
     let newUrl = currentUrl + '/' + universe;

     // 3. call Router.navigate with the new URL
     this._router.navigate([newUrl]);
}
```